# macbook air mid 13 overheating

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, cpu

My set up is macbook air mid 13 with i7 processor and 8GB of ram running OS X Yosemite. Which is plenty for my use, at least it has been. I usually have no more than 3 apps running as notes, reminders and safari. I also use statsbar to watch the performance and the usual is 1/3gb of ram free. The problem I started noticing is in the past week the machine has started overheating as I can feel it by touching the laptop and hearing the fan, which only used to happen when I tried to turn on all I could to see if the machine would handle it.

I supposed some would say that it also may depend on the amount of stuff I have open in safari as neither notes nor reminders use up the cpu that makes it overheat. I usually have up to 5 tabs open: youtube, couple of news websites and a couple of wiki tabs. Which the machine used to handle with no problems at all.

So my main question is how come the machine is going crazy and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: sometimes installed softwares..throw around  "agents" running in the background where they eat your memory, you may want to check for these.. give it a shot

Comment: How can I check for these?

Comment: Fiddle around your activity monitor

Comment: What software (if any) have you intentionally installed recently?

Comment: It's more likely to be dust & fluff build-up on the fans & cooler fins than anything else. Gotta clean them at least once a year if not more.

Answer (score -2):

Try uninstalling Adobe Flash. Flash doesn't work well on Macs. Flash games and Flash content in the Internet pages require a lot of processing power, which causes the CPU to go to the extremes and as a consequence heat builds up inside the Macbook. MacBooks (especially Air models) are known for poor inside ventilation.